# Help with COM Interop

Tags: .net, interop

I was trying to use [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with VS 2010. When I run the code A COM exception is thrown with the error code HRESULT: 0x80040216. How can I troubleshoot this issue. I can't find something meaningful when I google it.

Thanks.

Comment: When googling for HRESULTs it's always worth trying both the hex version and the decimal version. So I'd suggest trying your searches but using 2147746326 instead. After a quick search on that by itself I can't see anything obvious, but might be that you can find something that rings a bell to your code.

Comment: After doing what ho1 suggests I found out the the error code means "An object or name was not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is **VFW_E_NOT_FOUND**, which is defined in the old C/C++ header file "vfwmsgs.h", if it happens on the **RenderFile** method call, it means the file is just not there.

Comment: Marked your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the problem. The problem was that the media control could not find the avi file I was trying to play. When I copied the file to the application directory everything worked. So if you have this error check that the file you want to play is on the correct path.